How to set IntelliJ Language to English For DevSpace?
Whenever connecting to devspaces via intelliJ coder plugin, the IDE opens with the menu being in Korean. When I open a local project, then IntelliJ opens everything in English. I want everything in English. I am on macOS silicon with IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.3

I have tried deleting IntelliJ IDEA and redownloading the dmg. Also tried restoring default settings. Double checked to ensure there are no plugins related to languages that are installed in IntelliJ.

It's a known issue.
The solution is to update the remote IDE version to 2024.1.5+ or 2024.2+.

server region is us-west-2. Added both options you suggested to Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions and Contents/bin/jetbrains_client.vmoptions but no luck

@SatinderSingh Does it help if you disable localization plug-ins on Client?

I have 2 IDE instances, one connected to remote and one to local. For the remote, there are no plugins for korean. For local, there is a korean language pack which i disabled. Restarted intelliJ, reconnected, same issue. Got another IntelliJ license, same issue. Destroyed and recreated new workspace in devspace, same issue

@SatinderSingh Please see the updated answer.
